# Delete region using a button on the region itself

Tags: javascript, html, object, event-handling, object-literal

I have added a font -awesome button on a region - in order to delete the region; It looks like this:
[image]

here is the code that I added to the render function in the wavesurfer.regions.js:

```js
var deleteButton = regionEl.appendChild(document.createElement('i'));
deleteButton.className = 'fa fa-trash';
deleteButton.onclick = "wavesurfer.clearRegions();";
deleteButton.title = "Delete region";

  var css = {
 display: 'block',
 float: 'right',
 padding: '3px',
 position: 'relative',
 zIndex: 10,
 cursor: 'pointer',
 cursor: 'hand',
 color: '#129fdd'
  };
  this.style(deleteButton, css);
```

When I look at the HTML rendered, it does not contain the onclick event; And obviously when clicked it does nothing.
How do I get the onclick event to show in the rendered HTML first and foremost?
Second what is the propery way to get the clearRegions method do execute?

Here is a snipped of the rendered HTML:

```html
<region class="wavesurfer-region" title="0:53-1:18" data-id="wavesurfer_cvb9j0n784o" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 543px; width: 255px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392); cursor: move;"><i class="fa fa-trash" title="Delete region" style="display: block; float: right; padding: 3px; position: relative; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(18, 159, 221);"></i><handle class="wavesurfer-handle wavesurfer-handle-start" style="cursor: col-resize; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1%; max-width: 4px; height: 100%;"></handle><handle class="wavesurfer-handle wavesurfer-handle-end" style="cursor: col-resize; position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 0px; width: 1%; max-width: 4px; height: 100%;"></handle></region>
```

Tkx

Comment: perhaps you could provide some accompanying html? It looks as though the image you added is not showing here

Comment: I've added the image and the rendered HTML code...

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteButton.onclick = function(){};
```

Your syntax is wrong buddy. You dont need to put the quotes.
And if there is any other problem share your full code that will help solving the issue.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I've tried this, and if I put a console.log line, it gets printed when I click on the delete button. So half the problem is solved. The other half, is that the call to clear all the regions should be executed. Is there a possibility you could help or advise by checking out the code example pasted above?

Comment: The deleteButton is on the Region, the Region is on the WaveSurfer object. I'm not too sure what to put here. I guess a reference?

Comment: Is it possible to reference the Region object by getting the deleteButton's parent onbject?

Comment: Put the code you want to do inside the {}. Actually I dont know what region tag is. I havent come across that yet. Perhaps if you are still having problems your html and javascript